# Reference jQuery event handler in external js file

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, jquery-events

How do I use event handlers in jQuery when I have them in external files?

I'm using Phonegap to build an app, and for cleanliness sake, want to hold each jQuery function in a different js file.

But when I try to click the button that the event handler is bound to, nothing happens.

The event isn't fired.

I'm calling the js files after I load jQuery, just thought I'd say that.

External JS

```
$("#getname").click(function()
{
        var youruname = localStorage.youruname;
            
        var PostData =
        {
            youruname: youruname,  
        };
        
        $.ajax
        ({
            url: "http://www.yellowcabsavannah.com/tag/tag_logout.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: PostData,
            async: false,
            dataType: 'json',
            cache: false,
            success: function(data)
            {
                //do stuff
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Main File JS

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="tag.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="logout.js"></script>
<script src="http://jquery-ui-map.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ui/min/jquery.ui.map.full.min.js"></script>

<div id="toolbar"><p>Who: <span id="name">Tap To Choose</span> - </p><a href='#' id="tag" class="mapbutton">Tag</a><br /><a href='#' id="logout" class='mapbutton'>Logout</a></div>
```

Comment: Is this code wrapped in a DOM ready function?

Comment: Tried with it. Didn't work. I'll try again.

Comment: Place jQuery import at end of the body, check for correct file names referenced, make sure you are importing both jQuery and your function files correctly, check the console for any errors.

Comment: can you make jsfiddle with your attached external files?

Comment: Made a jsfiddle here. Like I said, the jQuery is in a separate file. I have made some updates to my code, so please take a look. Will update this question to reflect changed code. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/copilot0910/7EKvP/1/)

Comment: Your fiddle has a few issues. Your "So close" message is missing a `+` before the ending period, you have an extra closing curly brace before your `$(document).on` closing brace, and you haven't specified that you want to use jquery. Here's your fiddle with those fixed. http://jsfiddle.net/zhGAu/ It still doesn't quite work because the ajax isn't allowed.

Answer (score 0):

try by binding live or on

```
$("#getname").live('click',function(){...})
$(document).on('click',"#getname",function(){...})
```

Comment: Live is deprecated! Use `.on()` !! (assuming newer version of jQuery)

Comment: there must not be any difference

Answer (score 0):

Your html does not have an element with the id of `getname`. I am assuming you want to bind an event to the element with the id of `name` so try this:

```
$("#name").click(function() {

    alert("clicked");
});
```

Or change the span id from `name` to `getname` so

```
<span id="name">Tap To Choose</span>
```

becomes

```
<span id="getname">Tap To Choose</span>
```

and your event handler `$("#getname").click` should work just fine.